# Is it safe to upgrade WordPress 4.9.23 to 6.2.2 and WPBakery 5.5.5 to 6.13.0?

Tags: upgrade

I am in charge of a WordPress site that has had some very outdated plugins and themes. First, I upgraded PHP on the hosting from 7.0 to 7.4 which caused some PHP warnings that I got fixed by changing "continue" to "break" in two files of the Revolution Slider plugin. Then I upgraded the inactive themes and then all the plugins except for WPBakery.

Now everything works and everything is up to date except for the WordPress core (4.9.23, 6.2.2 available) and the WPBakery plugin (5.5.5, 6.13.0 available). Strangely enough, the WPBakery plugin update is offered in the administration despite the plugin not being registered and there is a prompt to register it. The compatibility of WPBakery 6.13.0 with both WP 4.9.23 and 6.2.2 is listed as unknown.

Should I leave it as it is or risk upgrading WordPress and/or WPBakery? If so, which one? If both, which one first? Thank you very much.

EDIT: changed "activated" to "registered" to avoid confusion - the plugin is of course activated in WP terms, it is not registered (i.e. "activated" in the WPBakery jargon).

Comment: "changing "continue" to "break"" - that does mean something else, unless you can see from the loop flow that it doesn't. Might be worth just getting an updated copy of Revolution Slider instead?

Comment: You probably need to ask WPBakery directly about compatibility sorry. Do you have a staging environment (or can you easily clone your site to make one?) where you can test the upgrade?

Comment: Generally though the latest WPBakery ought to work fine with the latest WordPress you'd hope! If not you can always just go to the latest version they do support, e.g. WordPress 6.1.x rather than 6.2.x, for the time being.

Comment: Thank you @Rup. Changing "continue" to "break" was advised elsewhere on the forum for the particular lines of the plugin and it doesn't seem to break anything (pun intended). I know it is not the best approach but I needed to fix the front-end quickly. I will get back to it. An updated version of Revolution Slider is not available for me and the customer doesn't have the budget to purchase it. I will ask WPBakery and if they are not sure, I will setup a staging environment.